# <Plug> was printed to the buffer instead of execute

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, neovim, snippets

I am using neovim with `deoplete.nvim` and `neosnippet.vim`. I am trying to make `TAB` key do both navigating through the popup menu and expand snippets when it's able to.
Here is my config.

```
" <TAB>: completion
inoremap <expr><TAB> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : neosnippet#expandable_or_jumpable() ? "\<Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)" : "\<TAB>"
inoremap <expr><CR> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<CR>"
inoremap <expr><Esc> pumvisible() ? "\<C-e>" : "\<Esc>"
```

I am successfully to make `Tab` navigating through popup menu but I won't be able to expand the snippet.

For example, when I have `function` and press `Tab`. Instead of expand the snippet. It became `function<Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)`

Step I went through:

1. `:n test.js`
2. `func` -> `Tab` -> select `function` and press `Enter`
3. Press `Tab` again.
4. Output `function<Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)`

I am not sure what goes wrong here. Please help.

Comment: Try `imap` instead of `inoremap`.

Comment: @VanLaser it works, but I don't quite understand. Can you help me explain?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I'm not close to a pc, I hoped someone would link/explain it by now. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984322/regarding-the-recursive-mapping-of-vim long story short, with <Plug>, you want recursive mapping, which otherwise you don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `inoremap <expr><TAB> ...` also has a `<Plug>`-mapping on the right-hand side of the mapping. These mappings only get expanded when you use `:imap`.

So, though [you should normally use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html), this is one exceptional case where you need to allow recursive mappings.